# Python : Returning a pyGTK object for packing

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

How to pass GTK object among classes and functions ?

I have a GUI class, that is a GTKWindow, and I have a player class, that is a vbox with a play button and a slider, and GST pipeline playbin.

(pseudo-code)

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.play_button = gtk.Button()
        self.slider = gtk.HScale()

        self.hbox = gtk.HBox()
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.play_button, False)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.slider, True, True)
        def getbox():
            return self.hbox

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, dname = None):
        player = Player()
        playerbox = playerbox.getbox
        vbox = gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start (playerbox, False, False, 1)
```

But

```
TypeError: Gtk.Box.pack_start() argument 1 must be gtk.Widget, not instancemethod
```

Maybe it's not the right way to do it, and all boxes *must* live in the same class everytime..?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `getbox` method? Why not just use `playerbox.hbox`?

Comment: I'll be damned. Why isn't your comment an answer, so I can accept it? Thank you *very* much, Blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neglected to actually *call* the `getbox` method. Instead of `playerbox = player.getbox`, you need to write `playerbox = player.getbox()`. Writing the former extracts the function object itself, which is why `pack_start` complains that it is receiving an `instancemethod` as argument 1.